# Labels for irreducible symmetric group characters

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Using GAP I can produce irreducible characters for symmetric group easily enough. For example:

```
G:=SymmetricGroup(5);
Irr(G);
```

Then, for example `Irr(G)[4];` outputs:

```
Character( CharacterTable( Sym( [ 1 .. 5 ] ) ), [ 6, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] )
```

However the irreducible characters are labelled by partitions. Is there a way I can get GAP to tell me that `Irr(G)[4]`, for example, is labelled by the partition `[3,1,1]`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first create the group, and then calculate the character table, this is done by a generic character table routine that does not know the special representation theory of the symmetric group.

There is an alternative way to calculate the character table of a symmetric group, using the Murnaghan-Nakayama formula. This is called as `c:=CharacterTable("symmetric",5);`   (or replace 5 by your favorite degree)

Then `ClassParameters(c)` and `CharacterParameters(c)`are lists that give the associated partitions for the classes and the characters, e.g. the 4th entry is `[1,[3,1,1]]`, indicating one character parameterized by the partition $1^23$.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed.